# Malicious Javascript - What it does?

Tags: javascript, security

What this javascript does? It's a buffer overflow? It's a xss? what it does? What is the decoded version of this farbbibliothek[x] array?

```
<SCRIPT> 
farbbibliothek = new Array(); 
farbbibliothek[0] = new Array("#FF0000","#FF1100","#FF2200","#FF3300","#FF4400","#FF5500","#FF6600","#FF7700","# 
FF8800","#FF9900","#FFaa00","#FFbb00","#FFcc00","#FFdd00","#FFee00","#FFff00","#FFee00","#FFdd00","#FFcc00","# 
FFbb00","#FFaa00","#FF9900","#FF8800","#FF7700","#FF6600","#FF5500","#FF4400","#FF3300","#FF2200","#FF1100"); 
farbbibliothek[1] = new Array("#00FF00","#000000","#00FF00","#00FF00"); 
farbbibliothek[2] = new Array("#00FF00","#FF0000","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","# 
00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","# 
00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","# 
00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00","#00FF00"); 
farbbibliothek[3] = new Array("#FF0000","#FF4000","#FF8000","#FFC000","#FFFF00","#C0FF00","#80FF00","#40FF00","# 
00FF00","#00FF40","#00FF80","#00FFC0","#00FFFF","#00C0FF","#0080FF","#0040FF","#0000FF","#4000FF","#8000FF","# 
C000FF","#FF00FF","#FF00C0","#FF0080","#FF0040"); 
farbbibliothek[4] = new Array("#FF0000","#EE0000","#DD0000","#CC0000","#BB0000","#AA0000","#990000","#880000","# 
770000","#660000","#550000","#440000","#330000","#220000","#110000","#000000","#110000","#220000","#330000","# 
440000","#550000","#660000","#770000","#880000","#990000","#AA0000","#BB0000","#CC0000","#DD0000","#EE0000"); 
farbbibliothek[5] = new Array("#000000","#000000","#000000","#FFFFFF","#FFFFFF","#FFFFFF"); 
farbbibliothek[6] = new Array("#0000FF","#FFFF00"); 
farben = farbbibliothek[4]; 
function farbschrift() 
{ 
for(var i=0 ; i<Buchstabe.length; i++) 
{ 
document.all["a"+i].style.color=farben[i]; 
} 
farbverlauf(); 
} 
function string2array(text) 
{ 
Buchstabe = new Array(); 
while(farben.length<text.length) 
{ 
farben = farben.concat(farben); 
} 
k=0; 
while(k<=text.length) 
{ 
Buchstabe[k] = text.charAt(k); 
k++; 
} 
} 
function divserzeugen() 
{ 
for(var i=0 ; i<Buchstabe.length; i++) 
{ 
document.write("<font face='monotype corsiva' size=30><span id='a"+i+"' class='a"+i+"'>"+Buchstabe[i] + "</span></fon
t>"); 
} 
farbschrift(); 
} 
var a=1; 
function farbverlauf() 
{ 
for(var i=0 ; i<farben.length; i++) 
{ 
farben[i-1]=farben[i]; 
} 
farben[farben.length-1]=farben[-1]; 

setTimeout("farbschrift()",30); 
} 
// Zu Demonstrationszwecken***************** 
var farbsatz=1; 
function farbtauscher() 
{ 
farben = farbbibliothek[farbsatz]; 
while(farben.length<text.length) 
{ 
farben = farben.concat(farben); 
} 
farbsatz=Math.floor(Math.random()*(farbbibliothek.length-0.0001)); 
} 
setInterval("farbtauscher()",5000); 
text= " Test123 "; //h 
string2array(text); 
divserzeugen(); 
//document.write(text); 
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: What gives you the impression its malicious?

Comment: @m.edmonson - I've seen obfuscated malicious scripts where hex codes were evaluated into other commands. It's not inconceivable that it might be malicious (at a glance), though I agree with you that casual inspection disproves that. Maybe the color palette is hard on the eyes.

Comment: I know this is old, but if you're still around, @Fred, where did you find this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is perfectly harmless: It's an array of hexadecimal colour values. "Farbbibliothek" is German and means "Colour library".

It seems as if the code generates a number of text elements, and gives them various colours. I can not see anything dangerous in it.

[Here's](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ZCtPH/1/) a working JSFiddle. Looks nice!

Comment: a number of text elements and gives them various colors? I open this script in my browser and it only show a title, a black background and a small phrase in grey color. For this, the easier should be just define the color as black for background and grey for font. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Fred that is because your original code is broken (there are some additional line breaks). Check out my link, I fixed the code and added a `<a>` element

Comment: its funny how somebody would think this masterpiece of german engineering is some weird obfuscated, malicious code :D

Comment: @koko ahahahaha! Although I wouldn't go as far as to call that a 
*masterpiece* as such ;)

Answer (score 2):

For your convenience, here is a translation of the german words used in your code snippet:

farbbibliothek: color library
farben: colors
divserzeugen: create divs
farbschrift: colored font/scripture
farbverlauf: color gradient
buchstabe: character
farbtauscher: color changer

Answer (score 2):

It's just a 'hacker' pin up poster for a compromised site. It's about as harmless as a flashy billboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setInterval("farbtauscher()",5000); in it and it wasn't doing anything in Pekka's JSFiddle so I made a sample to see why...
http://www.abv8.com/farbbibliothek.html
...it cycles through colors

Comment: Wow, that's very nice. Thanks